# Peculiar CSS layout questions

Tags: css, layout

I'm trying to figure out how to write some css for a peculiar layout I haven't seen before. The image below contains the sections. For guidance:

- Section "1" is a header, that should be fixed within the alpha zone
- Section "2" is a div which ought to have a scrollbar when it gets too tall (determined by the height of the viewport/window)
- Section "3 "is a footer, that should be fixed within the alpha zone
- Section "4" is a right hand, fluid, container, that will have an iframe. The iframe itself will manage the scrolling.

Any thoughts?

[image]

My code at the moment is kind of all of the place, but this is the gist of how close I got:

```
CSS:
.controller {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
}
.controller header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 60px;
    width: 400px;
}
.controller footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 60px;
    width: 400px;
}
.controller .body {
    overflow: scroll;
}
.focus {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

Markup:

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <header></header>
        <div class="body">
        <footer></footer>
    </div>
    <div class="focus">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why u think it is peculiar?

Comment: Sure, it would be easy. But try and read something up on Google first, and then when you run into problems when you try, ask here.

Comment: Use fixed positioning, google will avail you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RkZTB/3/) for how to achieve this,

The style I used is

```
body, html {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.container {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
}
.container header {
    display:block;
    height: 10%;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#ff5;
}
.container .body {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height:80%;
    background-color:#f5f;
}
.container footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 10%;
    width: 25%;
    background-color:#5ff;
}
.focus {
    background-color:#ddd;
    position: fixed;
    left: 25%;
    width:75%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
.focus iframe{
    width:99%;
    height: 99%;
}
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: Ahhh, this is great thanks Sen Jacob. Do you know if it's possible to use precise heights for the header and footer (eg. 60px heights) and still achieve the desired effect?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'll try that too. BTW you could write scripts for that, or use [LessCss](http://www.lesscss.org/) or [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/) for complex ccs operations

Comment: I'm using SASS at the moment, but since the height depends on the visitor's viewport, I'm not sure if I can do it with css (other than using the `calc` css method)

Comment: I realized I could use the CSS `calc` function to do what I'd like. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit busy with my work. If you don't mind, please update your question with the solution.